# Generate preparedstatement with bean properties

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, prepared-statement

I have a bean named Customer, has 40 properties.I am using java prepare statement to insert bean data into database so every time i have to write setString() or setInt() can anyone suggest me how can i minimize this? means is there any shortcuts in Netbeans or Eclipse IDE to generate prepared statement with bean getter properties

```
int x = 0;
Connection con = null;
String query = "INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City,  PostalCode, Country) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?); 
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(++x, person.custName());
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 40 times
```

Comment: Have you thought of JPA bean? Then you work with POJO objects and backing framework like Hibernate does it for you behind the scene.

Comment: @Leos Literak- I am using simple jdbc

Comment: Yeah, but JPA would save your manual work with all these 'statement.setXY(obj.getZ())', that you do not like to write.

Comment: @Leos Literak- Thanks for your quick response,can you share some link

Answer (score 0):

with the help of the [bean-query](https://github.com/Jimmy-Shi/bean-query), you can convert your bean(the person object in your code) into a map with keys and values, then iterate for each entry of that map, and call `ps.setString(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());`